# Xbuild can't recognize SignAndroidPackage when using bamboo

Tags: apk, bamboo

I am trying to create a .APK file in **Bamboo** using the xbuild executable in a command task.  The way I thought it should work is like this:

```
CusomterApp.sln /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release
```

This however when I run the build will give this error. `Target named 'SignAndroidPackage' not found in the project.`  I have tried to build it without it but I am getting other errors instead.  I have tried changing the order of it and changing the target but it doesn't seem to create the apk file doing this.

I have seen in another question that someone created an apk file using this(not on Bamboo):

```
xbuild $ANDROID_PROJECT_FILE /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:Configuration=Release
```

So I thought I should have no problems with using this on **Bamboo** but the executable doesn't seem to recognize the **SignAndroidPackage** and doesn't work, any ideas on how to fix this?

I create a .IPA file for an IPhone app using mdtool, with this command `-v build -t:Build "c:Release|iPhone" CustomerApp.sln` and this works fine for creating the .IPA file so I would have thought that the .APK would be fine too.

I think that the problem is to do with using the solution file for the Android apk file, The bamboo will create a solution folder which has both iOS and Android files in it.  The iOS worked and built the **IPA** file when I used the **CustomerApp.sln** file.  The **apk** file does not build when I use the **CustomerApp.sln**.  If I use this `CustomerApp.Droid/CustomerApp.Droid.csproj` file I get a list of error's `Are you missing an assembly reference?`

When I was doing the IPA I got this error using the **CustomerApp.iOS/CustomerApp.iOS.csproj** file which I fixed by using the **CustomerApp.sln** file instead.  How can I fix this as the whole folder contains information that is necessary for the creation of the APK file?

I have found a problem that when I try to build the apk file using this:  `/p:Configuration=Release CustomerApp.sln` it gives me the error PCL assemblies not installed and it also has this warning : `Unable to find framework corresponding to the target moniker '.NetPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78'. Framework assembly references will be resolved from the GAC, which might not be the intended behaviour.` I don't know why this is happening as I looked for the profile in the folder specified and it was there.

I had this problem before when trying to use xbuild to create the IPA file but then I used mdtool and it worked fine, I think I need to use xbuild to build the apk file but I can't see how to fix it. I also tried to run it in the terminal of the mac and I got the same error. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you have to specify a .csproj, not a .sln. If you give it a solution file, you'll get an error complaining that it can't find the "SignAndroidPackage" target.